# Platform independent way of dumping vars onto screen

Tags: c++, memory, dump

Is there any platform independent way of dumping the variables created by your program onto a screen? say i write the program

```
#include <iostream>

void f(){
    std::string interal_data = "hello world";
}

int main(){
    f();
}
```

is there any way to get `internal_data` out without adding a `std::cout/std::stream` to `f()`? i want to output all of the data from my program, which is quite big, and i dont want to go to every other line and place a `std::cout`. how do debuggers do it?

im looking for ways to do this in c++

Comment: Ask a question about C++ *or* Python, because the answers for the two will have nothing in common.

Comment: i did ask a question about c++ or python. but i see what you mean

Comment: You could generate a map file to tell you where the variables are stored, but it doesn't tell you their values during run-time.

Comment: why don't you just use a debugger?

Comment: i want to show users the internal data

Comment: Assuming all platforms have a console? My DVD-player does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ehm... "without adding a `std::cout`/`std::stream`" is nonsense, if you want to output something, just do it. Debuggers work with magic, namely inspect your process and stuff, and have debugging symbols for your process which you do not have.

**Edit**: Of course, this may only be true for C++, as Python is a somewhat interpreted language, so you might pull it off with that. As I have no experience whatsoever with Python, I can't comment on that though. :)

Comment: oh.darn it. so when other programs show their internal data, the data has been hardcoded to cout?

Comment: @calc: No, but they know where in memory your variables live and can just extract them from there. That's what's called "debug symbols". :)

Comment: does it matter what other programs? i doubt you havent seen a program spit out data before

Answer (score 0):

**The question was about python and c++, but changed to c++ only ??**

In Python you can print every thing on `globals()` or `locals()` and, if the object is a instance of class which doesn't have a representation of your data, just print the `__dict__` attribute inside it. I.e. Go recursively printing every thing.

Pseudo code:

```
def show(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, (int, float, ...default types...)):
        print obj

    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for i,j in obj.items()
            print i, show(j)

    else:
         show(obj.__dict__)
```

then you do:

```
show(globals()) #or show(locals())
```

You may want to filter more cases, but that is the basic algorithm.